# Magento 2: i need update order summary when click custom option payment method checkmo

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, order-summary

need to know is how to update the order summary like reloading the component when we do something like choosing a select payment terms

[image]

My code:

> view/frontend/web/js/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method.js

```
getFee: function () {
    return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.fee;
}
```

> view/frontend/web/js/action/payment/select-payment-method.js

```
    define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'PCarts_PaymentFee/js/action/checkout/cart/totals'
    ],
    function($, ko ,quote, totals) {
        'use strict';
        var isLoading = ko.observable(false);

        return function (paymentMethod) {
            quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);
            totals(isLoading, paymentMethod['method']);
        };
    }
);
```

> view/frontend/web/template/payment/checkmo.html

```
<!-- ko if getFee() -->
    <p data-bind="text: '· Select payment term:'"></p>
    <!-- ko text: console.log(getFee()) --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko foreach: getFee() -->
    <p>
    <input type="radio"
           name="payment[fee]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': fee}, value: fee" />
    <label data-bind="attr: {'for': fee}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: description + ' (financial cost: '+fee+'%)'"></span></label>
    </p>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
```

Tanks for the help!